# Python: How to specify optimization level for entry_points usng setuptools?

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools, entry-point

I have a `setup.py` file which I use to create wheel distribution for my package. The `setuptools.setup()` function creates an entry_point, which enables the user to run my program directly from the command line.

The `setup.py` file looks something like this:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    ...
    entry_points={"console_scripts": ["foo = foo.__main__:main"],},
    ...
)
```

I would also like to specify the optimization level (`-O` or `-OO`), so when a user would run the `foo` command, the program would start in optimized mode (meaning the `__debug__` build-in constant would be set to False). Is this even possible to achieve? How?

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible. You could manually alter the _shebang_ that is written at the top of the files afterwards.

Comment: Neither source dists nor wheels include `.pyc` files, these can only be written by the installer. Try smth like `python -O -m pip install mypkg` to write optimized bytecode on installation.